# How to use Random.nextGaussian() to generate N doubles that sum to 1

Tags: java, random, normal-distribution

I want to generate N random doubles that their sum is 1.

Also, the N random doubles should obey normal distribution.

I understand `nextGuassian()` in `Random` can generate normal distributed number.

But how to achieve the goal above?

Comment: Generate N random doubles, sum them all up, and divide each of them 
by the sum.

Comment: @jesper damn, this is smart. could you please write yours as an answer

Comment: It's pretty standard normalization practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double[] generateNRandomDoublesWhichSumToOne(Random random, int n) {
  if (random == null) throw new NullPointerException();
  if (n <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

  double[] values = new double[n];
  double sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    values[i] = random.nextGaussian();
    sum += values[i];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    values[i] /= sum;
  }
  return values;
}
```

Comment: What if the N random doubles need to be zero or positive?

Comment: @JacksonTale use `Math.abs`. Note that you would no longer be generating normally-distributed values though.

Comment: yes, that's my point. if i use `abs`, then it is like half normally distributed. Anyway, to move the whole distribution rightwards to positives?

Comment: @JacksonTale however far you shift your distribution, you can always get a negative value, it's just less likely. If you need guaranteed non-negative values, the normal distribution is not the right choice.